# Unable to add certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities in Windows 7

Tags: windows, certificate

I am trying to add an apple developer certificate for sending Push notifications to my Trusted Root Certification Authorities section. I get an error like so: "The import failed because the store was read only, the store was full or the store did not open correctly"

I am logged in as an administrator. I can't think of any way to solve this. Has anyone been able to fix a similar issue before?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: You didn't mention if you tried doing this via the command line, MMC, etc. I've seen similar issues from the command line if I wasn't running with an elevated command prompt.

Comment: running it via the GUI..

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  Would you mind posing your solution, I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 14):

I managed to solve a similar problem I was having by following the [instructions here](http://casualtechs.blogspot.com.au/2010/06/problem-when-trying-to-import.html) (here adapting steps 3 and 12 to read "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" instead of "Trusted Publishers"):

---

1. Download and save the certificate.
2. Open the Certificate Manager

   - Hit Windows+R, or click on the Blue Vista icon in the lower left hand corner
   - In the "Start Search" box, type "certmgr.msc" (no quotes).
   - The certificate manager will open.
3. Right click on "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" from the folder list on the left.
4. In the pop-up menu, choose "All Tasks" >> "Import.."
5. Click the "Next" button
6. Click the "Browse" button
7. Browse to the location where the certificate is saved, click on it then click the "Open" button
8. Click the "Next" button
9. Select "Place all certificates in the following store"
10. Click the "Browse" button
11. Put a checkmark beside "Show physical stores"
12. Expand the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder
13. Click "Local Computer"
14. Click the "OK" button.
15. Click the "Next" button
16. Click the "Finish" button

---

Basically the bit I was missing when trying to import the certificate was to drill down into the "Local Computer" folder underneath the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder.

Comment: This also verified to work on Windows 10 given the same "Certificate Import Wizard" import failure error dialog.

Comment: Problem I have now is that the certificate, created with `New-SelfSignedCertificate` tool on Windows 10 places the certificate within `Cert:\LocalMachine\My>`, which is not browsable with WIndows File Explorer...

Comment: This works for when Visual Studio screws up creating the localhost certificate, as well.

Comment: I cannot find the "Local Computer" folder under "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" on Windows 11